# Regex matching for or sembol

Tags: regex

Hello I have a regex and its `(^|\W)(t)|(t\W*year)($|\W)`

my test case is

has to match

```
t-year
t
```

doesnt match

```
test123
```

but the problem for `test123`its matching it shouldn't match and also for `t-year` it is matching but only for `t` character
You can check from here https://regexr.com/6eqfi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might for example use

```
\bt(?:[^\w\s]year)?\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `t` Match literally
- `(?:[^\w\s]year)?` Optionally match a non word character except for a whitespace char
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sPQ3y5/1)